# Increase multiple values in nested array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a simple product schema

```
{
  "_id": "123",
  "purchased": 0,
  "options": [
    {
      "name": "Size",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "S",
          "purchased": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "M",
          "purchased": 0
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Color",
      "options": [
        {
          "name": "Red",
          "purchased": 0
        },
        {
          "name": "Blue",
          "purchased": 0
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Let's say a customer purchase 1 item of Size M color Red. How do I `$inc` the purchased value for each option and for the product itself?

P.S I am running mongo version 3.2.4

Comment: @Veeram I am running on v3.2.4

Comment: I feel like the `$[<identifier>]` with `arrayFilters` can do the work but I just realised its on v3.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like updating may be  your only option. If you choose to update you can try something like below in mongo 3.6 version.

Finds the document with `filter` criteria and `update` which includes new [positional identifier](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) to update matching elements in array inside `update` method.

Use `arrayFilter` options for applying query criteria on nested array to control what elements to update.

You may have to do two updates one for each Size and Color. Don't think you can update multiple elements of same array for different criteria.

For Size

```
db.getCollection('col').update( {} , { '$inc': { 'purchased': 1, 'options.$[type].options.$[option]purchased': 1 } }, { arrayFilters:[ { 'type.name': ‘Size' }, {'option.name':'S' }] })
```

For Color

```
db.getCollection('col').update( {} , { '$inc': { 'purchased': 1, 'options.$[type].options.$[option]purchased': 1 } }, { arrayFilters:[ { 'type.name': ‘Color' }, {'option.name':'Red' }] })
```

Comment: I accept this answer for v3.6. My workaround for current version is updating necessary objects on app level before update it to db with `$set`.